# Putnam 2000 Problem A4

Tags: integration, contest-math, improper-integrals

I was looking through the solution for problem A4 of the 2000 Putnam exam, this problem asks to show that the following integral converges: $$\lim_{B \to \infty} \int_{0}^B\sin(x)\sin(x^2)dx$$

This is shown via integration by parts and comparison to converging integrals like so:
[image]

My question is, in the solution, how can they replace the $0$ bound with a positive $\epsilon$? Wouldn't that change the result of the integral? For example when comparing to $\frac{1}{x^2}$, that integral converges when the smaller bound of integration is a positive real, but not when it is exactly $0$. So how is it allowed to change the $0$ bound for a positive real value?

Comment: Let $\int_0^1 \sin(x) \sin(x^2) dx =A$. Then $\int_0^B \sin(x) \sin(x^2) dx=A+\int_1^B \sin(x) \sin(x^2) dx$, so it suffices to show that the integral from $1$ to $B$ converges to some limit. There's no need to involve any $\epsilon$ different from $1$.

Comment: Using $\epsilon$ makes you think it needs to be small which is kind of misleading. you can just split into $0<x<1$ and $x>1$. For $0<x<1$, the integral obviously makes sense

Comment: @Stephen Why are you writing an answer in the comment section?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Why are you answering in the comment section?

Comment: Well @Arthur I'm not sure of a couple of things, 1. would the comment as stated be a full answer? If not then I didn't want to spend the effort to flesh it out. 2. Will this question be deleted eventually? If so then my answer would make it harder to delete. But I wrote the comment to at least help OP as the OP has given context and effort.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I'll admit that Stephen's comment is closer to a _full_ answer, but I'd say yours is a pretty substantial hint, and that's also something that belongs in the answer section, even in its current form, in my opinion.

Comment: @Arthur I do in fact agree, but I'd still rather not post as an answer to avoid having to bother with someone who disagrees.

Comment: Suppose that $\epsilon$ is very very close to $0$ or infinitely close to $0$.